# How to ask Mathematica to compute the given sum of the differences of the numbers of the given two sets?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, summation, number-theory

I have two sets of real numbers, say,

`set1= {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11}`

`set2= {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11}`

**Question**

How can I ask Mathematica to compute this sum of the differences between the numbers of $a$ and $b$ with the same order?

`sum = (a1 - b1) + (b2 - a2) + (a3 - b3) + (b4 - a4) + (a5 - b5) + (b6 - a6) + (a7 - b7) + (b8 - a8) + (a9 - b9) + (b10 - a10) + (a11 - b11)`

More precisely, if we have $an$ and $bn$, in the sum, for odd $n$, we have $(an-bn)$ but for even $n$ we have $(bn-an)$.

Comment: `Total[set2-set1]`? Basic arithmetic operations are executed elementwise between lists of identical lengths, and `Total` does exactly what it says it does.

Comment: This is not what I asked, it is not a simple subtraction; if we have $an$ and $bn$, in the sum, for odd $n$, we have $(an-bn)$ but for even $n$ we have $(bn-an)$

Comment: One has to distinguish even and odd length, otheriwese the answer of @eyorble is o.k.:  `If[OddQ[Length[set1]], 1, -1] Total[set1 - set2]`

Comment: The subject header is a bit misleading. What is wanted, primarily, involves operating to reverse alternating elements, so just one list at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
Plus @@ Apply[Subtract] /@ MapAt[Reverse, Transpose[{set1, set2}], {1 ;; ;; 2}]
```

Another way:

```
Total[MapAt[-# &, set2 - set1, {2 ;; ;; 2}]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Rereading the problem I realized I interpreted the result incorrectly.  This should work.

```
setb = Array[b, 11];
seta = Array[a, 11];
# . (-1)^Range[0, Length@# - 1] &[seta - setb]
```

> a[1]-a[2]+a[3]-a[4]+a[5]-a[6]+a[7]-a[8]+a[9]-a[10]+a[11]-b[1]+b[2]-b[3]+b[4]-b[5]+b[6]-b[7]+b[8]-b[9]+b[10]-b[11]

Answer (score 6):

No @'s or #'s:

```
set1 = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12};
set2 = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12};
(-1)^Boole[OddQ[Length[set1]]] (set1 - set2) // Total
(* -a1 - a10 - a11 - a12 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5 - a6 - a7 - a8 - a9 + 
    b1 + b10 + b11 + b12 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + b7 + b8 + b9 *)

set1 = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11}
set2 = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11};
(-1)^Boole[OddQ[Length[set1]]] (set1 - set2) // Total
(* a1 + a10 + a11 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 - 
   b1 - b10 - b11 - b2 - b3 - b4 - b5 - b6 - b7 - b8 - b9 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set1 = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11};

set2 = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11};
```

---

```
Total@MapIndexed[#1*(-1)^First@#2 &, set1 - set2]
```

`(* a1 - a10 + a11 - a2 + a3 - a4 + a5 - a6 + a7 - a8 + a9 - b1 + b10 - \ b11 + b2 - b3 + b4 - b5 + b6 - b7 + b8 - b9 *)`

Check:

```
(a1 - a10 + a11 - a2 + a3 - a4 + a5 - a6 + a7 - a8 + a9 - b1 + b10 - 
   b11 + b2 - b3 + b4 - b5 + b6 - b7 + b8 - 
   b9) == ((a1 - b1) + (b2 - a2) + (a3 - b3) + (b4 - a4) + (a5 - 
     b5) + (b6 - a6) + (a7 - b7) + (b8 - a8) + (a9 - b9) + (b10 - 
     a10) + (a11 - b11))
```

`(* True *)`

Answer (score 1):

```
(Array[(-1)^#&, Length@set1]//#.set1-#.set2&)==sum 

(* True *)
```

Original Answer:

```
(Plus@@Subtract[set1[[2;;;;2]],set2[[2;;;;2]]]
    +Plus@@ReverseApplied[Subtract][set1[[1;;;;2]],set2[[1;;;;2]]])==sum

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
Total@(If[! 
  OddQ[Det[
    Position[
     Transpose[{set2, 
       set1}], #]]], #[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[1]] - #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{set2, set1}])
```